# I can't make the download progress bar from tqdm to show the progress

Tags: python, python-3.x, tqdm

I want to add a download progress bar with tqdm. The problem is that it shows me this :

```sh
0%|                                                                           | 0/11535.92578125 [00:00<?, ?KB/s]
```

And it downloads the file without showing a any progress. Here is my code:

```
s = requests.Session()
r = s.post(url, login_data)
response = s.get(link_to_pdf, stream=True)
total_size = int(response.headers['content-length'])
# download the pdf
print(pdf_filename)
with open(pdf_filename + '.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    for data in tqdm(iterable=response.iter_content(chunk_size=chunk_size), total=total_size/chunk_size, unit='KB'):
        f.write(response.content)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you did not write the data you write the request in 1 time not in chunks, jsut replace response.content that you write to file in the data chink you got from tqdm

```
  with open(pdf_filename + '.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    for data in tqdm(iterable=response.iter_content(chunk_size=chunk_size), total=total_size / chunk_size, unit='KB'):
        f.write(data)
```

Comment: @Iakovos Belonias was this helpful ? is so please vote

Comment: Yes thank you very much. Silly mistake from my side.